# Android Error in values-v21/values-v21.xml

Tags: android

I am not getting what is the problem in my Android Studio. I have also tried reinstalling the software but it is still giving me the same error.

```
>>>Error:(302) error: resource dimen/notification_action_text_size(akacom.example.reena.myapplication:dimen/nofication_action_text_size) not found.
>>>Error:(302) resource dimen/notification_action_text_size (akacom.example.reena.myapplication:dimen/notification_action_text_size) not found.
>>>Error:failed linking references.
>>>Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>>>Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>>>Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>>>Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: what is the version of device that you use to debug? Remove version specification (v21) from resource file

Answer (score 0):

In your res/values-v21.xml add this

```
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/notification_action_text_size</item>
```

your style should be like this

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.NotificationActionText" parent="">       
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/notification_action_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your values-v21.xml file you are referencing the resource dimen/notification_action_text_size, but it is not defined anywhere in your local resources or your dependencies.
This resource was added in API 21, make sure you have dependency on appcompat-v7:21.0.+ or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error show instead of the file remain in drawable or layout folder. I had same issue. I resolved it by uninstalling the app.